# how to map changing cluster-ip to host name in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have installed k8s on my Ubuntu 20. All pods are reachable from host Ubuntu with IP address, but not using service name. For that to happen, I have to add service name in host machine's /etc/host file. But the problem here is, every time the pod's IP changes after reboot and I have to update /etc/host entries all the time.

Is there any solution for this problem?

```
/home/ravi/e2-interface>sudo kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                           AGE
default       kubernetes                                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                           16d
kube-system   kube-dns                                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP            16d
ricinfra      service-tiller-ricxapp                      ClusterIP   10.98.94.194     <none>        44134/TCP                         6d21h
ricplt        aux-entry                                   ClusterIP   10.105.149.143   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                    6d21h
ricplt        r4-influxdb-influxdb2                       ClusterIP   10.110.14.243    <none>        80/TCP                            6d21h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-kong-proxy                NodePort    10.107.12.178    <none>        32080:32080/TCP,32443:32443/TCP   6d21h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-prometheus-alertmanager   ClusterIP   10.104.86.76     <none>        80/TCP                            6d21h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-prometheus-server         ClusterIP   10.102.224.176   <none>        80/TCP                            6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-a1mediator-http              ClusterIP   10.105.45.1      <none>        10000/TCP                         6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-a1mediator-rmr               ClusterIP   10.108.188.147   <none>        4561/TCP,4562/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-alarmmanager-http            ClusterIP   10.111.239.130   <none>        8080/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-alarmmanager-rmr             ClusterIP   10.106.30.195    <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-appmgr-http                  ClusterIP   10.110.110.91    <none>        8080/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-appmgr-rmr                   ClusterIP   10.110.96.28     <none>        4561/TCP,4560/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-dbaas-tcp                    ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2mgr-http                   ClusterIP   10.101.210.88    <none>        3800/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2mgr-rmr                    ClusterIP   10.101.245.34    <none>        4561/TCP,3801/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-prometheus-alpha      ClusterIP   10.97.95.213     <none>        8088/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-rmr-alpha             ClusterIP   10.100.36.142    <none>        4561/TCP,38000/TCP                6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-sctp-alpha            NodePort    10.108.215.136   <none>        36422:32222/SCTP                  6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-o1mediator-http              ClusterIP   10.96.196.67     <none>        9001/TCP,8080/TCP,3000/TCP        6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-o1mediator-tcp-netconf       NodePort    10.104.237.252   <none>        830:30830/TCP                     6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-rtmgr-http                   ClusterIP   10.105.27.42     <none>        3800/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-rtmgr-rmr                    ClusterIP   10.110.0.158     <none>        4561/TCP,4560/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-submgr-http                  ClusterIP   None             <none>        3800/TCP                          6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-submgr-rmr                   ClusterIP   None             <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 6d21h
ricplt        service-ricplt-vespamgr-http                ClusterIP   10.98.139.191    <none>        8080/TCP,9095/TCP                 6d21h
ricxapp       aux-entry                                   ClusterIP   10.99.152.66     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                    6d21h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-http           ClusterIP   10.99.222.68     <none>        8080/TCP                          15h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-rmr            ClusterIP   10.97.149.3      <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 15h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-example-http                ClusterIP   10.101.14.166    <none>        8080/TCP                          2d1h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-example-rmr                 ClusterIP   10.97.129.85     <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 2d1h
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface>


/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface> ping 10.101.210.88
PING 10.101.210.88 (10.101.210.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
^C
--- 10.101.210.88 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3078ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.045/0.056/0.076/0.012 ms
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface> ping  service-ricplt-e2mgr-http        -----------> to make this happen I have to add entry in /etc/host
ping: service-ricplt-e2mgr-http: Temporary failure in name resolution
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface> ping  service-ricplt-e2mgr-http.ricplt    
ping: service-ricplt-e2mgr-http.ricplt: Name or service not known
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
/home/ravi/e2-interface>
```

Thanks

Comment: Kubernetes has a very isolated network environment, and you shouldn't expect to be able to connect to Pods from outside the cluster other than through NodePort Services or Ingresses.  I would not expect an ordinary user to have direct login access to a Kubernetes Node in any case.

Comment: if this is the case, then why I am able to ping Pod (with cluster IPs) even using ip address? see the above log.

Comment: Have you tried [endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#endpoints) concept in kubernetes.

Comment: @Dharani Dhar Golladasari  I have no idea on that. Just a one-liner about this would be helpful for me to dig this more...."how it will provide me a persistent IP again a service which will not change across reboot?